# MakeSchool MakeNotes swift tutorial | Create a global variable

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have question regarding MakeSchool swift tutorial. During the implementation of MakeNotes in Part New Note Controller tutorial asksto create selected note giving some kind of hint. 
"Can you add a selectedNote variable to the class to store the selected Note? Hint you need to uncomment the first commented line so the selectedNote can be assigned."

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //1
    //selectedNote = notes[indexPath.row]    

    // 2
    //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ShowExistingNote", sender: self)    
  }
```

I tried to follow all the steps but my program crashes at this line. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Atalyk,

You have not provided the reason for crash or crash log. So here are the two possibilities I see.

**Possibility 1 :**

You might not have declared selectedNote variable.

*Solution*

in yourViewController declare a property named selectedNote before uncommenting the line 1. You have not specified the type of data you gonna save in notes array so can't provide you the perfect declaration of selectedNote variable.

like,

```
var selectedNote : notes_data_type_here!
```

The statement will create an implicit optional variable called selectedNote for you. I have declared it as class variable because I believe you gonna use it in prepareForSegue. You have not provided enough code though just guessing.

**Possibility 2**

Your notes array might be nil. It might be possible while copying from tutorial you used differrent array as a datasource for your tableView and might be accessing nil array in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

*Solution*

Check if your notes array is being used as your tables data source. If no in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, use the array you used as dataSource to access the selected object.

This should solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable in the class not the extension!

```
class blah blah: (UItable blah){
var selectedNote : Note!

more blah blah
```

That should allow your whole program to access the variable!